# When using cgroup v2, is there command line tool equivalent to cgexec command?

Tags: linux, cgroups

As we know, there is command-line management suite, among which there is cgexec command, in cgroup v1. We can start a process immediately under control group.

When we are using cgroup v2, is there command line tools equivalent to cgexec command? So that we can start a process under control immediately, instead of starting the process first, then moving to some cgroup with echoing its pid?